# Facebook not redirecting to "next" page after logout

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

In phonegap app i am using this url to logout

```
window.location.href="https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next="+encodeURI(MY_URL)+"&access_token="+fbToken;
```

Here `MY_URL` is one url defined in `Settings >> Advanced >> Valid OAuth redirect URIs` text box.

After logout facebook redirect to page not found. Sample of `MY_URL` is `http://localhost/dogroups_fork/www/#/home`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong method to prepare your parameter for insertion into an URL context.

Had you done a

```
console.log(encodeURI('http://localhost/dogroups_fork/www/#/home'));
```

you would have noticed, that this just gives the same value `http://localhost/dogroups_fork/www/#/home` back unaltered.

The *correct* method to use here is `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: but i dont think that url encoding is issue here cos if i use `http://www.example.com` it works

Comment: With your parameter value, if you don’t encode it properly, `#` ends the query string part of the whole URL.